# bootstrap-datepicker.1.5.0, bootstrap 3.3.5: date vanishes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a fairly simple datepicker. It instantiates fine. I set an initial date.  in the input field in the form. I click on the field and the picker pops up.  I choose to **NOT** select a date but click outside the picker to close it.  The input field is set to empty.

If I do set a date all is well.

I am using noConflict mode from the b-datepicker docs:

```
var datepicker = $.fn.datepicker.noConflict(); // return $.fn.datepicker to previously assigned value
$.fn.bootstrapDP = datepicker;                 // give $().bootstrapDP the bootstrap-datepicker functionality
```

I am configuring my picker as:

```
$("#startDate").bootstrapDP({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    todayHighlight: true
}).on('hide', function(e) {
    // `e` here contains the extra attributes
    console.log("startDate hide");
    console.dir(e);
    console.log("date:" + $("#startDate").bootstrapDP('getDate'));
});
```

In the case where I do NOT select a date I hoped that using the `hide()` method would let me have access to the `<input>` field's value before it is cleared but no joy.

The `hide()` method does get the `e` param but in the no-select case the `date` member is missing.  The `dates` array is there but empty.

What am I missing?

Comment: did you figure this out??  it's really annoying

Comment: No, I went a different way, didn't have time to mess with the datepicker..  I have years of data in a DB table.  I was hoping for a pretty calendar to narrow down the selectable dates.  Instead I query a list of available years and months and present that as a select list sorted in decreasing order.

Maybe I;ll get around to looking at the datepicker thing again in the future.

Comment: oh, my problem was solved by figuring out that I was binding the textbox value to the date from the database incorrectly.  I was just setting the value of the textbox without doing `.bootstrapDP('set', val);`